# How to correctly instantiate QQuickItem-derived object from C++?

Tags: c++, qt5, qtquick2

What is the correct way how to create instance of my own object derived from `QQuickItem` from C++ code?

Currently I'm creating new objects with following snippet:

```
//setup default values
MyType* quickItem = new MyType;
quickItem->setParent(parent);
quickItem->setParentItem(qobject_cast<QQuickItem*>(parent));
QQmlEngine::setObjectOwnership(quickItem, QQmlEngine::JavaScriptOwnership);
```

it's working great but `void componentComplete()` isn't executed as same as `isComponentComplete` flag isn't set.

Is it safe to call `componentComplete()` method manually after object creation?

Or there any `QmlFactory` which is able to create C++ objects and perform correct initialization?

Comment: Maybe [this link](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-definetypes.html) can help? Actually it is a `QObject`, so...

Comment: Thanks for link. I think I read each page in Qml/Qt documentation about hundred times, but unfortunately I didn't find any mention about this topic.  

There is no mention (on provided link as same as on any another Qml documentation) how to create pure QQuickItem directly from C++ and invoke componentComplete() event.

Comment: Ok, got it, let me add an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem is that there is a wrong expectation on what should happen when you create that object.

As you can see from the [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qquickitem.html#componentComplete), `QQuickItem::componentComplete` overrides `QQmlParserStatus::componentComplete`, that is a pure virtual member method.

If you look at the [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qqmlparserstatus.html#componentComplete) of `QQmlParserStatus::componentComplete`, it states that:

> Invoked after the root component that caused this instantiation has completed construction. [...]

From your example, it seems to me that there is no root object that causes that instantiation, for you are allocating it explicitly.
Because of that, there is no reason for which that method should be invoked and you are confirming that, so everything is working as expected.

Was that what you were expecting? Maybe no, so that's maybe the error.

**EDIT**

You asked also:

> Is it safe to call componentComplete() method manually after object creation?

Well, I'd export the type as suggested in the link I posted in the comments, then I'd instantiate objects from the QML environment, because it seems to be the right approach as well as the expected one.

Comment: To your second part of answer (the edited one). This solution unfortunately isn't possible. I would need to create c++ QQuickItem component from another c++ QQuickItem component during it's creation/initialization. The only solution would be to encapsulate QQuickItem with Qml component and than create it back from c++ but this seems to me as overkill.

Comment: It makes sense, I don't know which is the real problem, so I can only do my best in giving answers and suggestions. ;-) ... Anyway, is it clear now why that method is not called? Sometimes the documentation is hard to read, for it is spread all over several pages.

Comment: Yes, the reason why method is not called is clear now. What I still would like to know is if the QQuickItem classes should be created in way I described or if there is other recommended method.